# Would it be troublesome if I put plaques and medals in my checked luggage? (USA)

Tags: usa, airlines

I am from the USA, which may be a relevant information, since I would think that TSA rules are a little stricter than others.

Anyway, I want to bring my medals and plaque (which seems to have rectangular metallic stickers on them). I'm just worried that it might raise red flags because they're metallic and circular/rectangular.

Anybody have any experience or knowledge on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like regular sports awards? I would think that would be *very* common and normal.

Comment: Yes, I mean just regular awards. Do you think plaques are also common and normal? I'm bringing 7 plaques and 8 medals, and I'm just worried that this quantity is unusual or something.

Comment: Certainly not, unless there is something inherently suspicious about them. Are they enormously oversized? Do they belong to random people (in such a manner as to make them look stolen)?

Comment: Nah, they're normal sized and all belong to me. (I apologize for the very late response.) Also thanks for your affirmation :)

Comment: The TSA has well published rules, which makes life easier for those who travel. But all countries I have traveled in and between has about the same rules as the TSA and keep to them in about the same way. When rules change, some countries will be faster to take up the change and some slower, but after a while they are all on the new rules. The rules are 'different' in that they do not just copy them, but most of the time there is very little difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never put anything of value in checked luggage.
That is monetary value as well as emotional value.

First of all, much of the luggage is opened for checking (I do not know how much) and there is a big risk of things going missing because they dropped out or some innocent reason like that.
Then there is theft, still not very common but a real risk.
And lastly, there is the risk of your luggage going missing, losing its labels or going to a wrong airport so far away that they just forget to return it to you.

Unless the weight is too much, keep it in hand luggage.
If for whatever reason you can not bring them in hand luggage, better leave them home.

There is no reason they can not travel in checked-in luggage.
In themselves the plaques and medals should not worry the TSA security staff, but they might want to open the case to check out what is in your luggage, thereby raising the risk of them going missing. (I assume by accident.)

When you fly, almost always, airlines and insurance companies will only insure your check-in luggage to a given low maximum and if your plaques and medals are valuable or precious metals you are very likely to be above that value.

Answer (score 1):

If they do raise red flags, your bag may be inspected more closely. (I had this experience once when trying to bring a huge number of metal pin-on buttons in a carry on.) However, there is nothing wrong with bringing these items on board or checking them so there is nothing to worry about.